# What is approximate worst case garbage collection duration on big heaps

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I need a rule of thumb regarding the maximal time of full garbage collection. The motivation is to be able to distinguish between a faulty JVM process and a process which is under GC.

Suppose I have a regular general-purpose server hardware, HotSpot JVM 8, the heap size is 20G-40G, no specific GC and memory options are set. What is a reasonable time limit for GC to complete? Is it 5 minutes, 20 minutes or up to hours?

Update:
My application is a memory intensive offline job dealing with big data structures. I don't need to tune GC at all. 10 seconds and 10 minutes pauses are bot fine if this limit is known.

Comment: 5 or 20 mins ? does it sound reasonable to you that your program will halt for that long ?

Comment: I would be really surprised if you really need to think "minutes" here. I would *hope* for a few *seconds* at max. And beyond that: this still depends on the characteristics of your application.

Comment: I remember running into an example of 18 seconds GC which was considered as *really bad*...

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: agreee with @GhostCat, highly depends on type of application, and good educated java programmer. Many materials exist usually on keywords "low latency java". How write code, how select and parametrise GC.

Comment: 1. "the heap size is 20G-40G" not allways add more memory is a solution if Yout think there is low memory. 2. For some solution (cache) can be used "off heap" memory. I continue: google "low latency java"

Comment: I haven't seen a GC pause of even 20 *seconds* for about 20 years, but then maybe I lead a sheltered life :-|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very difficult to quantify how long GC "should" take because it depends on a number of factors:

- How big the heap is.
- How *full* the heap is; i.e. the ratio of garbage to non-garbage when you run the GC.
- How many pointers / references there are to traverse.
- Which GC you are using.
- Whether this is minor "new generation" collection, a major "old generation collection" or a "full" collection.  The last is typically performed by the fall-back collector when a low-latency collector cannot keep up with the rate of garbage generation.
- Whether there is physical <-> virtual memory thrashing occurring.

There are a couple of pathological situations that can cause excessive GC times:

- If the heap is nearly full, the GC uses an increasing proportion of time trying to reclaim the last bit of free space.
- If you have a heap that is larger than the physical memory available, you can get into virtual memory "thrashing" behavior.  This is most pronounced during a major or full GC.

---

If you do need to pick a number, I suggest that you use one that "feels" right to you, and make it a configuration parameter so that it is easy to tweak.  Also, turn on GC logging and look at the *typical* GC times that are reported there.  (Particularly when the server load is high.)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the gc pause time counts on **millisecond** in most of the time. If a gc take more than one **second**, I think your application **must be tuned anyway**.

And then just as the comment said, **the gc pause time depends on the characteristics of your application**. So if you want a rule of thumb regarding the maximal time of full garbage collection for your application, I advice you to collect the **gc.log** and **make statistics on it**, then you will know how long is the pause time in a poorly gc.

Answer (score 0):

For batch jobs where latency does not matter much there are better measures than pause times:

a) MB of garbage collected / time / cpu core

Low collection rates usually indicate some pathological cases like swapping, transparent huge page consolidation or some edge-cases in the GC such as humongous reference arrays being scanned.

b) application throughput - the ratio of wall time spent in application code vs. wall time spent in GC.

Long GCs aren't a big issue if they occur infrequently.

Both can be obtained by running GC logs through [GCViewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer)

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is:
1.configure on JVM parameter and turn on GC logs,check the GC logs, you will see how long the GC takes
2. GC won't be minutes, I saw around 13second pause time which customer was very badly affected.